# Count 'word' in row & column range. Only if that row has another specific 'word' written in it

Tags: google-sheets

Hope you can help me with this google sheets question. Very new to this but ill try to make my question as straightforward as possible!

Example scenario based on my problem:

I have a production schedule in google sheets that tracks 4 people working on 3 projects (Project X, Project Y, Project Z). Day by day and week by week. Please see the below link for an example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a61LqAaEb1a86kx9s2HAGiwYDPXKh-uiefI0o-QPvaY/edit#gid=0

I need a counter to count how many days were spent on each project by each resource by project.

eg.

- Project X

  - Person 1: 4 days (need this as formula)
  - Person 2: 6 days (need this as formula)
  - Person 3: 11 days (need this as formula)

Hope that's clear! Let me know if not. Thanks in advance.

Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 'Proj X' try

```
=Query({A2:A16, ArrayFormula(mmult(N(C2:G16="Proj X"), transpose(column(C1:G1)^0)))}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")
```

and see if that works.

EDIT: To look for partial matches, try

```
=Query({A2:A16, ArrayFormula(mmult(--regexmatch(C2:G16&"", "Proj X"), transpose(column(C1:G1)^0)))}, "Select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col2 > 0 group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")
```

Comment: Wow! That is incredible! Doing my best to understand what you did. But it has pretty much blown my mind.

Might be asking too much, but I have noticed an issue that arises when I impliment our end, which is that our cells have the project name and task name eg. 'project x - task1' or 'project x - task 2' written in the same cell. Is there anyway to make it count cells including 'project x' instead of specifically? Does that make sense? Ill update a new tab in the example sheet to show what I mean if you do have time to look that would be hugley apreciated!

Comment: Yes, there is. I updated the formula in my post and in the spreadsheet you shared.

Comment: AMAZING! Stab in dark - One more thing that would be amazing, if possible, would be for the formula to fetch the 'project x' from the cell above it? You obviously are a genius at this so just thought I would check if that was even possible? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: You mean the text part in the formula with a cell reference? Like so C2:G16=I1. or in the second case: --regexmatch(C2:G16&"", I1).Check the updated formulas in your spreadsheet.